# Rails 5.x: How can I add a route at runtime without overwriting original routes table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Say I have a controller action that should result in a new route being added to the routes table:

```
def make_route
  vanity_url = params[:vanity_url]
  vanity_redirect = params[:vanity_redirect]
  return render json: { status: 400 } unless vanity_url && vanity_redirect

  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get vanity_url, to: redirect(vanity_redirect)
  end
  render json: { status: :ok }
end
```

When I trigger this action, it does add the new route but completely erases the rest of the table! How do I prepend, append or otherwise map through the original routes when drawing the new table?

Comment: Not sure your use case, this is quite the anti-pattern. But, if you must, http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4 has some insight as to how to do this. Be warned though that unless you're storing this in some sort of persisted data store, you'll lose it every time you restart your server.

Comment: I would argue that your solution will not work. Imagine what happens if the server restarts or there is a new version deployed? Then all additional route that you created will be gone. Instead, store the URL and the redirect URL in a database table and have a catch-all route that calls a controller method that checks this table and does the redirect.

Comment: Backing on what @spickermann said, what you probably want to do is create a new record, have a route like `/:vanity_url`, match that to a controller action, query said model based on `params[:vanity_url]` and then redirect.

Comment: Could you share some more context about what you are trying to achieve? If this is only for redirects, why not create a dedicated controller for that, and just use standard routing? I've never come across a usecase in which you require dynamic routes.

Comment: Thanks all. I was always planning to persist the vanity urls in the db, but was looking for a way to not restart the server each time a new record was added to db. I had envisioned the routes would be set at initialization from the db, but the catch-all route to controller action that does a db lookup makes more sense and then no restart is necessary either.

Answer (score 12):

In prod's env Rails load configuration once and not listen to changes. If you want to build custom routes you must [reload routes](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/reload_routes!) each time when the new route was added:

```
Rails.application.reload_routes!
```

Also, that does not append a new route to your route file and any server restart reset your router to default. But you can save new routes to the database and recreate them when the server starts or build your routes inside `routes.rb` from ENV variables.

But if you want to use `draw` and need a new route just once:

```
Rails.application.routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = true  #add this line
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #new route
end
```